# Word 2013 formating

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, format

Is it possible to do specific thing based on words with separate formats or words. For example putting line break before the first italic word (there might be a sentence in italic but for it to put line break before first and after the last word). and putting line break before every number (specific number for example every 100).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do both with find and replace.

> putting line break before the first italic word (there might be a sentence in italic but for it to put line break before first and after the last word)

- open find and replace dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- select "find what" box

  - go to format / font and select italic
  - you can leave it blank, as with formatting specified it'll look for all text with that formatting
- to "replace with" enter:
  `^p^&^p` (^p: line break, ^&: the text found)
- press replace all

[image]

> and putting line break before every number (specific number for example every 100)

just enter `100` to "find what", `^p^&` to "replace with" and press "replace all"